# click image and make description box and larger image display

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

how are you supposed to use the mouseover event listener or getradiovalue()
how do I incorporate it in the already code i have?

```
`<div class="container">
    <div class="juno">
        <img src="juno.jpg" 
        width="450" height="150" 
        alt="Roland Juno (a classic)">
        <!--align="right"-->
        
        <p id="demo">ROLAND JUNO SYNTHESZIER</p>`
```

Comment: show more detail code pls

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Mouseover will trigger every time your cursor hovers over element as well as its children. On the other hand, mouseenter will trigger only when your cursor hovers over the element you assigned the event listener to.
Here is a [preview](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_event_mouseenter_mouseover#:%7E:text=mouseenter%20and%20mouseover.-,The%20mouseover%20event%20triggers%20when%20the%20mouse%20pointer%20enters%20the,moved%20over%20the%20div%20element.) of difference.

When using those, you will add event listener just like with click and define a function which will be triggered on that event. Then you can change a size, grab some value, or do whatever you want.

In your case you could use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` so you can control what happens on both.
If you need click listener you could just replace `mouseenter` with `click` and that will work.

In functions you can use something like `targetImageEl.style.width = "500px"`.

```js
let targetImageEl = document.getElementById("target-image");

targetImageEl.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => {
  // function that triggers when you hover over the image
  console.log("enter");
});

targetImageEl.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
  // function that triggers when you move cursor away from previously hovered image
  console.log("leave");
});
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="juno">
    <img src="juno.jpg" width="450" height="150" alt="Roland Juno (a classic)" id="target-image">
    <!--align="right"-->

    <p id="demo">ROLAND JUNO SYNTHESZIER</p>
  </div>
</div>`
```